# Validate the selected value in a WPF combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

Like the title says, I am trying to validate my form, but I have an issue getting the combobox value:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox_Country" 
          Validation.Error="Validation_Error"
          Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                         Path=Form_Country,
                         ValidatesOnDataErrors=true,
                         NotifyOnValidationError=true}"/>
```

Which is then validated with my class FormValidation like so:

```
            public string this[string columnName]
            {
               get
            {
               string result = null;

               if (columnName == "Form_Country")
               {
                  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Form_Country) || !verifyNumericValue(Form_Country))
                    result = "Please choose a correct option.";
               }

            }
```

I use these functions to call the validation in my form.

```
    private void Confirm_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = _errors == 0;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Confirm_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _generic = new UnidadValidation();
        grid_UnidadData.DataContext = _generic;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void Validation_Error(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
            _errors++;
        else
            _errors--;
    }
```

I wish to get the selected value, not the selected text. What is my best option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stupid, stupid stupid lack of observation on my part. If you were to change the ComboBox's `Text` to `SelectedValue` instead like so:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox_Pais" 
          Validation.Error="Validation_Error"
          SelectedValue="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                  Path=Escuela_Pais,
                                  ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, 
                                  NotifyOnValidationError=true}"/>
```

One will get the selected value and NOT the text.

For those of you who might want to read on it, I found the original tutorial here.

[WPF TextBox Validation with IDataErrorInfo](http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/06/wpf-textbox-validation-idataerrorinfo.html)

Comment: If you think that's stupid, I traced my lack of validation errors to having previously set `Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" `