# Combobox Binding with validation rules

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a problem with my binding on a `ComboBox` which I don't understand why it does not work:

The following code binds the item on the object and it works perfectly:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Name="comboBoxDefinedBy" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStandard}" Margin="0,0,5,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DealerTemplateComboBox}"  SelectedValue="{Binding DefinedBy_Id, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Id">                
</ComboBox>
```

The following does not work, whereby the validation rule works perfectly:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Name="comboBoxDefinedBy" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStandard}" Margin="0,0,5,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DealerTemplateComboBox}"  SelectedValuePath ="DefinedBy_Id">
    <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
        <Binding Path="Id" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <customValidationRules:ComboBoxIsNotEmptyValidationRule></customValidationRules:ComboBoxIsNotEmptyValidationRule>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: You noticed that your original Binding is to `SelectedValue` and that your Binding with Validation Rule is to `SelectedItem`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'does not work'?

Comment: The moment when you realize that you should not have send this post- 
The binding did not work- so the correct working is of course:

Comment: The moment when you realize that you should not have send this post- 
The binding did not work- so the correct working is of course including SelectedValue="{Binding DefinedBy_Id, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Id".

Answer (score 2):

As this [article](https://adamprescott.net/2010/09/28/wpf-combo-box-validation/) says you've got a few options.

You can bind your `SelectedItem` to a property and do the validation on that like this

```
private MyDataObject _someData;
public MyDataObject SomeData
{
    get
    {
        return _ someData;
    }
    set
    {
        _ someData = value;
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.MyProperty))
            throw new ApplicationException("SomeData is required");
    }
}

<ComboBox.SelectedItem>
    <Binding Path="SomeData" ElementName="Window">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <ExceptionValidationRule />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</ComboBox.SelectedItem>
```

Alternatively, you can create your own validation rule and then do it like this

```
public class MyCustomValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (value is MyDataObject)
        {
            var myDataObj = (MyDataObject)value;
            if (myDataObj.CheckCustomBusinessRules())
                return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }

        return new ValidationResult(false, "Invalid selection!");
    }
}

<ComboBox.SelectedItem>
    <Binding Path="SomeData" ElementName="Window">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <local:PersonValidation />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</ComboBox.SelectedItem>
```

Taking this a step further another option, as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923922/validate-the-selected-value-in-a-wpf-combobox) suggests, is to replace the `ValidationRules` with something like `IDataErrorInfo`. This [article](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/) gives a nice overview of the different ways validation can be done.